# Python - modelling probability

Tags: python, random, probability

I have a simple problem. I need a way to make a function which generates 0s in p percent cases and 1s in all other cases. I tried doing it with random.random() like this:

```
p = 0.40

def generate():
    x = random.random()
    if x < p:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

However, this doesn't seem like a good way. Or it is?

Comment: That's simple, obvious, and correct. What do think is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know. I just had a strange feeling about this so I thought I'd better ask. Thanks.

Comment: You could do `return x >= p`, which is shorter, but maybe less readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your current method is perfectly fine, you can verify this by performing a few trials with a lot of attempts.  For example we would expect approximately 600000 True results with 1000000 attempts:

```
>>> sum(generate() for i in range(1000000))
599042
>>> sum(generate() for i in range(1000000))
599670
>>> sum(generate() for i in range(1000000))
600011
>>> sum(generate() for i in range(1000000))
599960
>>> sum(generate() for i in range(1000000))
600544
```

Looks about right.

As noted in comments, you can shorten your method a bit:

```
p = 0.40

def generate():
    return random.random() >= p
```

If you want `1` and `0` instead of `True` and `False` you can use `int(random.random() >= p)`, but this is almost definitely unnecessary.