# Probability function to generate values instead of calling random

Tags: python, statistics

In my python code there are a few places where I have a population where there is `x` chance of something happening to each individual, but I just need the amount of people affected.

```
amount = 0
population = 500
chance = 0.05

for p in range(population):
    if random.random() < chance:
        amount += 1
```

My gut tells me there must be a less brute force way to do this than calling random.random() 500 times. Some math or stats terminology or function that I don't know.

```
amount = population * chance * random.random()
```

is too variable for what I need.

Comment: Seems like it would be related to a [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution).

Comment: Seems like dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992533/python-modelling-probability

Comment: @pecospest In this question, he's asking how to sum the values of n repeated trials.

Comment: I disagree that it is a duplicate; the 'duplicate' simply shows a different way to write a loop - this question asks 'how can I avoid writing a loop'?

Comment: @user2864740 Actually the "duplicate" just asks how to simulate a single trial.  There is no loop involved.

Comment: You are trying to create a sample.   If this is a school project code is fine if you have not done statistics before.    If you are studying statistics properly study the question and your fastest way will be to use a numpy for the distribution that you are modeling.    If you are writing real code and you want to speed it up use @augurar answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is not to execute the discrete loops but to use stochastic models (binomial distribution) to simplify it.

For special value ranges you can transform a distribution into another. For a large number of experiments (in your case `n=500`) the binomial distribution [can be approximated to a normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation).

May if you don't want to install `numpy` you can approximate this.

For your case (`n = 500`, `p = 0.05`):

[image]

[image]

With this you could use the `random` module again:

```
random.normalvariate(25, 4.87340)
```

I would recommend the solution with `numpy`. It should be the exact and fastest solution.

Answer (score 9):

The distribution of the sum of *n* 0-1 random variables, each with probability *p* is called a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters *n* and *p*.  I believe [`numpy.random.binomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) will do what you want.

Comment: @JayKyburz You can click the check button to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.